# Android TargetApi annotation and the Just-In-Time compiler

Tags: android, annotations, jit, android-annotations

I'm including Android Beam support for our app. But because we're still support 2.2 * *cough cough die froyo, die gingerbread, cough* * I've packed all the NFC code in the class `NfcHandler` with the TargetApi annotation to avoid lint warnings like this:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public class NfcHandler implements NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback
```

then from the `MainActivity` during `onCreate` I build the object if necessary like this:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        nfcHandler = new NfcHandler(this);
```

in the constructor it does all the necessary NFC stuff and later in the code `if( nfcHandler != null )` I pass the intent to it, so it can check if it's receiving a beam.

All good and great and it works most of the time.
But in rarely occasions Gingerbread devices crash with:

> 10-22 16:08:01.022    1734-1734/com.baseapp.eyeem.p0 E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.baseapp.eyeem.os.NfcHandler', referenced from method com.foo.MainActivity.onCreate

I mean, the class does exist and it's just a null object of it there.

Because our app on XXHDPI devices is 23mb and on the ldpi Gingerbread 5mb, I can see that the Just in time compiler (JIT) or some other runtime optimization is deleting the unnecessary resources. I wonder if it could be the same case of my NfcHandler class, because it's annotate for `ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH` it deletes it.

So the question is:

- what is happening actually happening and why am I getting this crash just once in a while and not every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, the class does exist and it's just a null object of it there.

`NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback` was added in API Level 14. Hence, it is not possible for Dalvik on older devices to load it successfully, as it will fail to resolve that interface.

Now, in principle, Dalvik should never try to load your `NfcHandler` handler class on Gingerbread devices, if the code snippet you show above is the only place that you are referring to it, or if all other occurrences have the same `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)` Java version guard block defending it.

What it suggests is that on these devices, `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is not returning the expected value, either because of a firmware bug or, conceivably, something some rooted device user did to tweak their environment.

Comment: The other code that references it is just a `if(nfcHandler != null && nfcHandler.handleIntent(intent)) return;` on the method that handles the activity intent. The device in question is one of our test devices nicknamed "shitty device", an HTC Wildfire S on 2.3.5. I'll give a try on packing the `NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback` in an internal object and report back

Comment: well it seems that it did the trick. Because the object was implementing an interface the JVM doesn't know it kept complaining about it and crashing once in a while. Thnks!

Comment: @Budius: would it suffice to guard the `nfcHandler.handleIntent(intent)` with `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I don't know, maybe it would. But everything is working now after I made the interface be a private object. So the only object that the VM "sees" before the version comparison is the one I created.